# A WARNING OCCURED WHEN I WAS INSTALLING ' PANDAS ' MODULE in "cmd"

Tags: python, pandas, pip

Image:

[image]

Code:

```
python -m pip install pandas
Collecting pandas
  Obtaining dependency information for pandas from https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/b7/f8/32d6b5aa4c4bc045fa2c4c58f88c325facc54721956c6313f0afea8ea853/pandas-2.1.0-cp311-cp311-win_amd64.whl.metadata
  WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ReadTimeoutError("HTTPSConnectionPool(host='files.pythonhosted.org', port=443): Read timed out. (read timeout=15)")': /packages/b7/f8/32d6b5aa4c4bc045fa2c4c58f88c325facc54721956c6313f0afea8ea853/pandas-2.1.0-cp311-cp311-win_amd64.whl.metadata
  WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ReadTimeoutError("HTTPSConnectionPool(host='files.pythonhosted.org', port=443): Read timed out. (read timeout=15)")': /packages/b7/f8/32d6b5aa4c4bc045fa2c4c58f88c325facc54721956c6313f0afea8ea853/pandas-2.1.0-cp311-cp311-win_amd64.whl.metadata
  WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ReadTimeoutError("HTTPSConnectionPool(host='files.pythonhosted.org', port=443): Read timed out. (read timeout=15)")': /packages/b7/f8/32d6b5aa4c4bc045fa2c4c58f88c325facc54721956c6313f0afea8ea853/pandas-2.1.0-cp311-cp311-win_amd64.whl.metadata
  WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ReadTimeoutError("HTTPSConnectionPool(host='files.pythonhosted.org', port=443): Read timed out. (read timeout=15)")': /packages/b7/f8/32d6b5aa4c4bc045fa2c4c58f88c325facc54721956c6313f0afea8ea853/pandas-2.1.0-cp311-cp311-win_amd64.whl.metadata
  WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ReadTimeoutError("HTTPSConnectionPool(host='files.pythonhosted.org', port=443): Read timed out. (read timeout=15)")': /packages/b7/f8/32d6b5aa4c4bc045fa2c4c58f88c325facc54721956c6313f0afea8ea853/pandas-2.1.0-cp311-cp311-win_amd64.whl.metadata
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='files.pythonhosted.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /packages/b7/f8/32d6b5aa4c4bc045fa2c4c58f88c325facc54721956c6313f0afea8ea853/pandas-2.1.0-cp311-cp311-win_amd64.whl.metadata (Caused by ReadTimeoutError("HTTPSConnectionPool(host='files.pythonhosted.org', port=443): Read timed out. (read timeout=15)"))
```

Comment: Don't SHOUT at us - we tend to not read questions where you SHOUT.

Comment: Please, improve your question, even though you are in a hurry. It will bring you some calm and peace of mind.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add "urgent" to my question?](/q/326569/4518341) TLDR: never, that's not what we're here for. Please take the [tour] and read [ask] to learn how to use this site constructively. Notably, Stack Overflow is a Q&A site, but there's no question here and it's not clear what exactly you need help with. Like to start, do you understand what the error means?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be a problem with the network connection.
Turn off proxy and try agin.

Or you can use mirror  sites, for example:

```
python -m pip install pandas -i https://pypi.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/simple
```

```
python -m pip install pandas -i https://pypi.org/simple
```

Comment: thanks bro ...  its solved by first link address (when the proxy was on )

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that there are several timeout errors, so it may simply be a network problem of yours or of the server from which you want to download the dependencies. Simply try checking your connection and try again in a few hours.